# How to Load an Entity Inside a Spring Data REST Server by Self Link?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Given a [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) (SDR) server built with [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin 2.2.5.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.2.5.RELEASE), is it possible to load an `@Entity` by self link *within* the server application?

I'm aware how to access it with an HTTP client, e.g. using curl:

```
$ curl localhost/users/1 # Responds with 200 OK and JSON representation
```

What I'm searching for is a mechanism to do this in the server using Java only, ideally using a standard SDR mechanism:

```
@Service
public class SelfLinkResolver {

    public Object findBySelfLink(Link self) {
        if (self == null || !self.getRel().equals(SELF)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-null self link expected");
        }
        return null; // How to return the entity using a standard SDR mechanism?
    }

    public void exampleCall() {
        Link self = new Link("localhost/users/1");
        Object entity = findBySelfLink(self);
        requireNonNull(entity, "Failed to load entity by self link");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with this solution, which uses SDR's `UriToEntityConverter`. In contrast to my question, it requires not only the self link, but also the entity class. It therefore doesn't fully answer my initial question.

I *guess* that there is no SDR solution that does not require the entity class, since there is no need for this within the framework, at least for usual API calls. SDR is always provided with the type information through the `Repository`, to which the self link refers. However, I didn't dive into other classes such as `PersistentEntities`, `RepositoryInvokerFactory` or `Repositories`, which might provide a solution for this.

**WARNING: My tested implementation differs from this. This code is untested, but should illustrate the idea.**

```java
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.RepositoryInvokerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.IanaLinkRelations.SELF;

@Component
public class SelfLinkToEntityConverter extends UriToEntityConverter {

    private static final TypeDescriptor URI_DESCRIPTOR = TypeDescriptor.valueOf(URI.class);

    SelfLinkToEntityConverter(@NonNull PersistentEntities entities,
                              @NonNull RepositoryInvokerFactory invokerFactory,
                              @NonNull Repositories repositories) {
        super(entities, invokerFactory, repositories);
    }

    @NonNull
    public <T> Optional<T> findBySelfLink(@NonNull Link self, @NonNull Class<T> entityClass) {
        checkArgument(self.getRel().equals(SELF), "Non-null self link expected");

        URI uri = self.expand().toUri();
        TypeDescriptor typeDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.valueOf(entityClass);

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T entity = (T) super.convert(uri, URI_DESCRIPTOR, typeDescriptor);

            return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException o_O) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(format("Failed to load %s: %s",
                    entityClass.getSimpleName(), self.getHref()));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An internal solution is parse your link and extract the ID (1 in your example), the call `repository.findById(id)`.

Another solution would be new a `RestTemplate`, call your own API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented the first to get it up and running some months ago. Calling the own API sounds too expensive to me. But both solutions are according to my understanding rather workarounds than a proper built-in SDR standard.

Comment: @aboger Where does the link URI `"localhost/users/1"` come from? Application internal or external? If internal, there must be an object holding the ID.

Comment: It's an external `String`, only. There no type information in the context.

Comment: There is no such SDR standard solution to deal with URI passed from external. Then you should consider carefully about your data flow. Maybe the ID is better than a URI string. Maybe some required value of the object (users in this case) is better than a URI string.

Comment: There must be such a solution since SDR needs one to do the job. That's why I wanted to reuse it. Actually I found a solution for this after digging deeper into the SDR code, I just don't know whether it's hacky or not. I will post it here. However, it requires type information in the context.

Comment: Oh now I understand, you probably meant that there is no such SDR standard solution to deal with URI passed from external _without the type information_. That makes sense since I also haven't found such. Thanks for your help.